# Android Studio runs Instrumentation tests as Junit Tests

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit

I have my instrumentation tests located in a separate module. I have applied the plugin `"com.android.test"` in `build.gradle` file and when I call `gradle connectedCheck`, the tests in the main source set are executing as instrumentation tests as expected on the device.

But when I try to run it from Android Studio (by right-clicking on a class and selecting Run), it tries to run the tests as normal Junit tests and give the following error:

```
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:224)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:207)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Process finished with exit code -3
```

I tried to edit the configuration and add a new **Android Instrumented Tests** configuration, but as soon as I select my test module, it displays

```
Error: The current project cannot be run
```

Note: The instrumentation tests in `src/androidTest/java` and the Junit tests in `src/test/java` work fine as they should. So, there's no dependency problems. The only problem is with a test module itself.

Comment: Can you paste the test.

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle`? I suspect you may not be using `androidTestCompile` to define instrumentation-specific dependencies.

Comment: @CodeBender did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @okset, I reported this to google and they fixed it in one of the Android Studio 3.0 beta releases: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64787165. That issue tracker also has a workaround (which i didn't test) if you need it.

Comment: I got this issue after upgrading to Android Studio 3.3 :'(

Comment: I got this issue using AS 4.0